# How can i access attribute's type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class named Employee.This class have 3 attributes:name,adress and supervisor.

Comment: Can you post a small code of the Employee class that has the attributes. Do you mean that they are properties in employee class and you want to associate them with attributes?

Comment: Attributes are normally called properties in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the supervisor of an Employee can be any other kind of `Employee` the supervisor should be an `Employee`, but if only Managers can be supervisors then supervisor should be `Manager`.

Just as a side note: Inheriting in this way is not always a good solution. You will run into lots of trouble if `Employee` can have multiple roles, like both `Developer` and `Designer`.
I recommend you to have a look at [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead of inheritance.